# How can I save disabled combobox and radiobutton in table using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

Is there any way to save the value of disabled select option and value of disabled checkbox in MySQl table using PHP. I already tried with readonly. Readonly is working fine with textbox, but not with drop down and checkbox.
Here is partial html code.

```
<tr>
<td width=241>First Name :
<input type="text" name="child_name" id="reg_no" value="<?php echo $row->eq_name;?>" readonly/></td>
<td align="center">Middle Name :
<input type="text" name="mid_name" id="reg_no" value="<?php echo $row->mid_name;?>" readonly/></td>
<td width="250" colspan="2">Last Name :
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="reg_no" value="<?php echo $row->last_name;?>"readonly /></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Category</td>
<td><input type="text" id="cast_cate" name="cast_cate" value="<?php echo $row->scat_id;?>" readonly/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
BPL <input type="checkbox" id="bpl" name="bpl" value="<?php echo $row->e_bpl;?>" <?php if($row->e_bpl=="Yes"){?> checked<?php } ?> readonly />
EWS <input type="checkbox" id="ews" name="ews" value="<?php echo $row->e_ews;?>" <?php if($row->e_ews=="Yes"){?> checked<?php } ?> readonly />
SGC <input type="checkbox" id="sgc" name="sgc" value="<?php echo $row->e_sgc;?>" <?php if($row->e_sgc=="Yes"){?> checked<?php } ?> readonly />
</td>
<td width="158">
Handicap<input type="checkbox" id="handi" name="handi" value="<?php echo $row->ehandi;?>" <?php if($row->ehandi=="Yes"){?> checked<?php } ?> readonly />
</td>
```

This is PHP Code -

```
$q2="insert into es_preadmission(pre_fname,m_name,pre_lname,pre_scat_id,pre_handi,pre_ews,pre_sgc,pre_bpl) values('".ucfirst($_POST['eq_name'])."','".$_POST['mid_name']."','".ucfirst($_POST['last_name']).$_POST['cast_cate']."','".$handicap."','".$ews."','".$sgc."','".$bpl."','".$_POST['house']."')";
$log_insert_exe=mysql_query($q2) or die(mysql_error());
```

I welcome any advice/suggestion

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the ones you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. `$_POST` data never goes directly in a query.

Comment: @tadman thank you for these valuable information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disabled means that it won't be submitted, and i'm not sure but i don't think there is readonly for option and input[type="checkbox"]. You can render at screen with disabled, but you will need to push values in hidden inputs for submitting them.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="test" name="test_display" /> // will be displayed
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="test" /> // will be posted
```